# Download a .docx file from s3, rewrite and upload to s3 again. Java 17 Springboot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, docx4j

I have a templates files (.docx) in a Bucket S3. These files contains text and variables that will be replaced with some content.
This replacement will be do with Docx4J.
Once it is replaced, I have to upload these files to S3 again.

When I get the file from s3 I use:

```
byte[] doc = s3Client.downloadFile(s3TemplateFolder, "example-template-en.docx", bucket);
```

For replace the variables in the file I use Docx4J:

```
  InputStream targetStream = ByteSource.wrap(doc).openStream();
  HashMap mappings = new HashMap();
  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(targetStream);
  VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
  mappings.put("Download_date", "asd!");
  wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().variableReplace(mappings);
```

The problem is when I have to upload the updated file to s3 again. S3client only support File type. I don't know how should I do for convert WordprocessingMLPackage to a File again.

If you can think of another way to do this, you are welcome :)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert on docx4j but you do have the save method on the `WordprocessingMLPackage` class that allows you to save to a file.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.docx4j/docx4j/latest/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage.html

The `OpcPackage` is a parent class of WordprocessingMLPackage so you should be able to call the save method that saves to a file.

> public void save(File file)
> throws Docx4JException
>
> Convenience method to save a WordprocessingMLPackage or
> PresentationMLPackage to a File. If the file ends with .xml, use Flat
> OPC XML format; otherwise zip it up.
>
> Throws:
> Docx4JException

You could use this to save the file and then upload it to S3.

You could also save the file to a byteArray using this method.

> public void save(OutputStream outStream)
> throws Docx4JException
>
> Save this pkg to an OutputStream in the usual zipped up format
> (Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_ZIP_FILE)
>
> Throws:
> Docx4JException Since:
> 3.1.0

And then use the contents of the OutputStream to save to S3.